# casperjs: how to retrieve a GET result from Jquery?

Tags: casperjs

here is my function

```
result = casper.evaluate(function() {
        $.get('IP/ajax.php', {a: 'get'}, function (json) {
            return json;
        });
       return 'hello world';
    });
```

Of course result will never get the json result as expected but will always get the "hello world" (or null if I comment the return 'hello world')

Is there an easier way to do that than using some promise in Jquery ?

Comment: Can you describe what are you actually trying to accomplish? Why are you calling ajax request in browser context?

Comment: I am used to use jquery for web instead of casperjs. Here for instance, I try to get some results from a sql query. This is a simple task. which I could do using url query paramerters like ajax.php?a=get.

Comment: the goal is to "pause" casper on this step until jquery returns a value.

Comment: Why don't you use jQuery in node environment?

Comment: Is there a jquery compatible module for casperjs ?

Comment: Just use node and add jquery as your dependency. If you provide full code or give me more details I can help you. This way it is unclear what you want  and don't think you got basic understanding of what casperjs is.

Comment: Some nodes modules does not work with CasperJS. Not sure Jquery module for node does work on capserJS